# External Extension Chrome OS through Admin Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

We have an external extension hosting service setup to serve XML and a crx file packed with chrome.

The XML is formatted with:

```
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="1.0">
<app appid="xxxxxxxxxxx">
<updatecheck codebase="https://extensions.site.com/crx/build.crx" version="1.9.6"/>
</app>
</gupdate>
```

We edit group policy to point at the xml file (we've also tried the crx file with and without an update URL) using the Google Admin Console to target Chrome OS devices.

[image: Add chrome app or extension by ID]

We configure using the built in setting to deploy to Chrome OS.

We also have appropriate settings regarding allowing external extensions.

[image: settings]

The extension refuses to install on Chrome OS enterprise (education).

Comment: how are you installing it?

Comment: @Baby_Boy through the GPO in the admin console. The force install setting that works for webstore extensions.

Comment: what resources have you used so far, and where did they lead you?

Comment: @Baby_Boy I've used Google's documentation and have contacted their support and have an open ticket with engineering at Google Enterprise and an open ticket on the Chromium OS support forum. Was fortunate enough to find internal documentation from Google that got me as far as I did.